# Detect combination of letter, numbers special characters between round brackets

Tags: regex

I would to know how to detect letters, combination letters and numbers between rounded brackets. In my examples below, it must not detect the year.

Detect:

```
Sample (test 2011)
Sample (test-2011)
Sample (test)
```

Do NOT detect

```
Sample (2011)
```

Comment: Please always specify the language or tool you intend to use. [Regex implementations vary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), and a solution that works in one language may not work in another.

Answer (score 1):

example that would match your test-samples in JavaScript regex:

```
^\([a-z\- ]+[0-9]*\)$
```

^ matches start, and $ end
\( \) matches the brackets once
[a-z\- ]+ matches literals, blank and - once or more times
[0-9]* matches 0 to 9 zero or more times

**edit**
nevertheless, you should be more specific, and look at some kind of documentation too (especially, since there are thousand info pages for regular expressions around)

Comment: Should not know how to be more specific, crawled over the internet for a solution and didn't found one that suited me. I want to allow the year between the brackets and nothing else.. But i need the regex that reads out the forbidden ones, so can't add it to my php script.